# Knockout Sortable is blocking click into input

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-sortable

I am using a Knockout sortable on a table, and it works great - but the input that is on the row can no longer be clicked into.  I can tab to the inputs and they operate perfectly, but the sortable is blocking the clicks.  Any idea to get around this?  Thank you.

The part int he table I use it:

```
<tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', foreach: items }, kendoSortable: items"></tbody>
```

Template:

```
<script id="my-template" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: auto" data-bind="text: title"></td>
        <td style="width: 250px">
            <input style="width: 98%" data-bind="value: notes, event: { change: onNotesChanged }" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Let me know if I need to post more, thank you.

Comment: Do you have a sample? Generally inputs work fine inside of a sortable.

Comment: added, please let me know if you would like more details

Comment: ended up using this: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable